# OSX 10.10 CMake 3.0.2 and clang won't find local headers

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clang

On OSX 10.9 I had installed a variety of header libraries under

```
/usr/include
/usr/local/include
```

And everything worked fine.
Today I did the "free upgrade" to Yosemite, and suddenly everything stopped working.
Together with Yosemite, I also (previously) upgraded Xcode (note, I am not compiling using Xcode, but clang directly via command line).

I have a CMakeLists.txt which clearly includes /usr/include

```
set(INCLUDE_HEADERS ${INCLUDE_HEADERS}
             /usr/include
             /usr/local/include)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${INCLUDE_HEADERS})
```

Yet, when I try to compile, I instantly get:

```
fatal error: 'boost/lexical_cast.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
```

What's going on here? Anyone else experience this, or even know how to solve it?
Things were working fine in 10.9 (oh why did I upgrade?)
I may also be doing something wrong as I noticed that cmake was upgraded to 3.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonical way for such situations is:

```
find_package(boost REQUIRED)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()
```

It will add path to the BOOST header into compiler search path.

Comment: What is a reason to use `if(...)` statement if you mark package as "REQUIRED"?

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem and a solution.
Problem is that by default, clang appears to search only in the SDK folder of the platform:

```
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk
```

This didn't use to happen before, or I had somehow changed without knowing.
So, I changed my `.bash_profile` in my home dir, and added:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include:/usr/local/include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include:/usr/local/include
```

Close and reopen a new terminal, and now clang finds the include dirs, and works fine.
Although I'm troubled by the fact that only the latter (/usr/local/include) appears to be used with the -I flag.