# Mac OS X: clang-omp cann't find header files (xgboost installation)

Tags: c++, macos, include, clang, xgboost

I'm trying to build multithread supporting xgboost according to this [guide](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/build.md).
So i made fist three steps. But when i run:

```
cd xgboost
make
```

i get this message:

```
/Users/user/clang-omp/build/bin/clang++ -c -Wall -O3 -msse2 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -fopenmp -fopenmp -fPIC -o updater.o src/tree/updater.cpp
src/tree/updater.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'cstring' file not found
#include <cstring>
          ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [updater.o] Error 1
```

What am i doing wrong?

System:
Mac OS X 10.10.4

P.S. I've tried to set system variables like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834553/osx-10-10-cmake-3-0-2-and-clang-wont-find-local-headers), but it didn't work.

Solved:
Just found file "cstring" on my mac. There were some variants. I took folder:/usr/local/Cellar/clang-omp/2015-04-01/libexec/include/c++/v1/
and set variables:

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/clang-omp/2015-04-01/libexec/include/c++/v1/:
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/clang-omp/2015-04-01/libexec/include/c++/v1/:
```

It wasn't the end of the story. Another mistake occured:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "__ZNKSs7compareEPKc", referenced from:
  __ZN7xgboost14BoostLearnTask3RunEiPPc in main.o
  __ZN7xgboost7learner12BoostLearner10InitObjGBMEv in main.o
  __ZN7xgboost14BoostLearnTask8InitDataEv in main.o
...
```

Solved in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533321/error-when-compiling-some-simple-c-code).
So I just correct Makefile like this:

```
export CC = clang-omp++
export CXX = clang-omp++
```

And it's worked.